# composite_primary_keys on Rails 4 Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, composite

I am trying to use the `composite_primary_keys` gem on my application.
I made this "Enterprise" model that have "related" and "branch" attributes. Those 2 are my composite PK.

```
class Enterprise < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.primary_key = :related, :branch
end
```

Using rails console, I can find my first Entreprise by using `e = Enterprise.find([1,1])` without a problem.

The thing is: I can't make it work on my controller...

My show action, for example:

```
@enterprise = Enterprise.find(params[:id])
```

It gives me the error:

> Couldn't find Enterprise with 'related,branch'=1,1
>
> Parameters: {"id" => "1, 1"}

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`params[:id]` is a string - you need to create an array out of it:

```
@enterprise = Enterprise.find(params[:id].split(',').map(&:to_i))
```

Comment: afaik, `map(&:to_i)` should not be necessary.

Comment: @p11y - with the spaces and whatnot, it normalizes stuff - I don't know how `find` would react to `("1", " 1")`

Comment: @UriAgassi I checked `#find` takes `"1"` or `1`.. no issue. `2.1.0 :003 > ReportingGroup.find('1').blank?
  ReportingGroup Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "reporting_groups".* FROM "reporting_groups" WHERE "reporting_groups"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", "1"]]
D, [2014-06-02T19:39:30.656376 #11388] DEBUG -- :   ReportingGroup Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "reporting_groups".* FROM "reporting_groups" WHERE "reporting_groups"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", "1"]]
 => false ` ..

Comment: @ArupRakshit - my problem was not with `"1"` but with `" 1"` (with the space at the start)

Comment: Ohkay... Sorry then for disturbing you.. :)

Comment: As space is problem, then just for safety we can do `params[:id].gusb(/\s+/,'')`...

Answer (score 2):

Composite primary key supports for string params for finding an object. The thing is you should not give space between the primary keys. So your param should be like this,

```
params => {"id" => "1,1"}
@enterprise = Enterprise.find(params[:id])
```

Try this, it should work.

Comment: As *space* is problem, then just for safety we can do `params[:id].gusb(/\s+/,'')`..